# `nix-build` process caught up in locking, never terminating

Tags: nix, nixos

On NixOS 20.09, I experience the problem when running an [obelisk](https://github.com/obsidiansystems/obelisk) project. E.g. I do `ob init` and add `regex-tdfa` to the dependencies of `frontend/frontend.cabal`.

Then

```
> nix-build -A exe --no-out-link -vvv
```

And I get a never ending output of lines similar to this:

```
building of '/nix/store/njiphyrb4xcnnckclvv0r2ns65yipnkp-mmorph-1.1.3.tar.gz.drv': woken up
building of '/nix/store/nsncr60fii4fwki70bb5ishf1hzq89b5-coreutils-8.31.drv': created
building of '/nix/store/nsncr60fii4fwki70bb5ishf1hzq89b5-coreutils-8.31.drv': woken up
building of '/nix/store/pvq34lb5r34bypfl53hx8kibakzqw7fc-gnused-4.7.drv': created
building of '/nix/store/pvq34lb5r34bypfl53hx8kibakzqw7fc-gnused-4.7.drv': woken up
building of '/nix/store/xr4aygslk3lqdz9wnsq04vpbm4v68vk5-glibc-locales-2.27.drv': created
building of '/nix/store/xr4aygslk3lqdz9wnsq04vpbm4v68vk5-glibc-locales-2.27.drv': woken up
building of '/nix/store/m3dzp25n0g4fwlygdhvak1kk8xz906n9-bash-4.4-p23.drv': init
building of '/nix/store/m3dzp25n0g4fwlygdhvak1kk8xz906n9-bash-4.4-p23.drv': loading derivation
acquiring write lock on '/nix/var/nix/temproots/21932'
downgrading to read lock on '/nix/var/nix/temproots/21932'
building of '/nix/store/m3dzp25n0g4fwlygdhvak1kk8xz906n9-bash-4.4-p23.drv': have derivation
acquiring write lock on '/nix/var/nix/temproots/21932'
downgrading to read lock on '/nix/var/nix/temproots/21932'
acquiring write lock on '/nix/var/nix/temproots/21932'
downgrading to read lock on '/nix/var/nix/temproots/21932'
acquiring write lock on '/nix/var/nix/temproots/21932'
downgrading to read lock on '/nix/var/nix/temproots/21932'
acquiring write lock on '/nix/var/nix/temproots/21932'
downgrading to read lock on '/nix/var/nix/temproots/21932'
acquiring write lock on '/nix/var/nix/temproots/21932'
downgrading to read lock on '/nix/var/nix/temproots/21932'
```

The process `nix-daemon` runs with 100% CPU-time. If do `sudo nix-build ...`, the `nix-build` process itself runs with 100% CPU-time, never terminating.

Others tried to reproduce and didn't encounter the problem. It might be related to my hardware. [See this reddit post with comments](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/my1bql/obeliskreflex_building_fails_for_a_number_of/).

**Further information**

- The problem only occurs with packages in the frontend, i.e. packages that are being compiled by ghcjs. The log output doesn't point to any ghcjs-related problem, though.
- The package `regex-tdfa` is not the problem, as I also experience the same problem now, just building the obelisk static files derivation on a more complex project, and with a couple of other packages.
- I run NixOS 20.09, on an NVME SSD hard drive
- The `ob run` command always works, w/o any problem (I can see the functioning result in development mode)
- I posted [the issue](https://github.com/obsidiansystems/obelisk/issues/855) in the `obelisk` project and collected some details about the problem there.
- I asked about this problem on the [NixOS forums, here,](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/nix-daemon-hangs-while-building-an-obelisk-reflex-frp-project/13028/2) and received some hints

Comment: edit from Michael Litchard: "not a haskell problem": I only ever encounter the problem when compiling with ghcjs. I think it's got more to do with how nix works, but I don't really know where the problem arises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved to a conventional hard drive and the problem is gone. Of course an actual solution would be nice on how to avoid this issue on an nvme.

EDIT: The hard-drive was never the problem. The locking issue apparently has been silently solved somewhere around this commit: https://github.com/flyingcircusio/nixpkgs/commit/ac60476ed94fd5424d9f3410c438825f793a8cbb